# how to create a self-consist jar file in eclipse which includes jdbc?

Tags: java, jdbc, jar, export

I write a program which create a random number(ID) and name name from jdbc.
but when I export jar file, the database don't work.

what can i create a complete file or document consist of jdbc file and jar file

Comment: JDBC File? Did you mean a file like a database?

Comment: my information about jdbc is tin!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: how to connet to jdbc after compile my code ?

Comment: Do I need special tools to my program jdbc Get connected

Comment: Only Java SE. You can use SQLite, but need add the JAR for conected. Or you can use MS Access: `String myDB ="jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=C:/data/neptuno.MDB";`

Answer (score 0):

Be more clear, do you want to include the JDBC Driver into a runnable JAR file? If so, you can achieve this using some IDE like Netbeans or Eclipse. Both allow you to export a JAR file containing the required libs included.

In Netbeans: 
- right-click on project folder, go to properties
- expand Building -> encapsulation
- make sure "copy dependent libraries" are marked